# How to set a string to the text of a label in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am trying to set a string as the text of a label in tkinter program but it is not visible on the window. Please help me. A piece of code is here :

```py
str=input()   
lbl=Label(win,text=str)
lbl.grid(row=11, column=1, ipadx=20, ipady=10, sticky=W + S)
```

Comment: unless you didn't specify win, this works perfectly fine. Also, avoid using python inbuilt classes as variable names.

Comment: did you use `win.mainloop()`?

Comment: Yes, I am using win.mainloop() as well. The window appears but the label doesn't.

Comment: Better avoid using `input()` in GUI application.  Use `Entry` widget instead.

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a keyword in Python. Try renaming it to `str1`

```py
from tkinter import *
str1=input()
root = Tk()
lbl=Label(text=str1)
lbl.grid(row=11, column=1, ipadx=20, ipady=10, sticky=W + S)
root.mainloop()
```

This is what I am getting

[image: Click for the output of the above]

Comment: I used str1 in place of str but the it is still not appearing. Also please tell me how I can read a string from a file and set it as a text of a label.

Answer (score 0):

This code probably will work,

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_string = ""

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("300x200+50+50")
        self.entry = Entry(self.root)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.onReturn)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.my_label = Label(self.root, text="Initial text!")
        self.my_label.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def onReturn(self, event):
        self.my_label.config(text=self.entry.get())
        self.entry.delete(0, END)

    Application()
```

Comment: Can you explain how and why does it work? What are essential parts of the solution?

Comment: Why don't just use `text=my_string`?